# Is it possible to change the style of selected date of React Native calendar?

Tags: react-native

I am making a React Native app in which calendars in it.
Is it possible to change the style of selected date of React Native calendar?

As shown in the image, I want to change the style of (6/10/2019) like the image.

[image]

Is there any way to change this? Or which module should I use for this?
Those are modules that I know related with calendar.

> ```
> react-native-calendars
> react-native-calendar-events
> react-native-calendar
> react-native-calendar-strip
> react-native-bpk-component-calendar
> react-native-calendar-select
> react-native-calendario
> react-native-dates
> react-native-event-calendar-customized
> react-native-calendar-reminders
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Here's an example

```
<Calendar
  // Date marking style [simple/period/multi-dot/single]. Default = 'simple'
  markingType={'custom'}
  markedDates={{
    '2018-03-28': {
      customStyles: {
        container: {
          backgroundColor: 'green'
        },
        text: {
          color: 'black',
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        }
      }
    },
    '2018-03-29': {
      customStyles: {
        container: {
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          elevation: 2
        },
        text: {
          color: 'blue'
        }
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to mark the selected date as ellipse?

Comment: I take a look at the documentation and didn't found anything. Maybe you can do that by creating another function to specify it.